# pip install requirements.txt allowing local path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

I understand this should be possible via:

`pip install --proxy=http://$proxy_ip:8080  --find-links file:///usr/local/lib/myrepos -r requirements.txt`

(proxy being a requirement of my environment here).

This goes progresses ok through the requirements.txt until it reaches the line where I have a library of my own that is not on pypi.
Line(S):

`MyAwesomeLib1`
`MyAwesomeLib2`
`MyAwesomeLib3`

those fail. (Could not find a version... version: none)

The content of `/usr/local/lib/myrepo`
is
MyRepoName1/MuAwesomeLib1
MyRepoName2/MuAwesomeLib2
MyRepoName3/MuAwesomeLib3

Things I tried:

- point to `--find-links file:///usr/local/lib/myrepos/MyRepoName1/`
- point to `--find-links file:///usr/local/lib/myrepos/MyRepoName1/MuAwesomeLib1`
- replace in `requirements.txt` , `MyAwesomeLib1` with `/usr/local/lib/myrepos/MyRepoName1/`  (this works, but it is not what I need)

Question 1 to which I couldn't find an answe would be: what's the expected content of `/usr/local/lib/myrepo` ? is it expecting anything specific?

Other than that I am at loss as to why this is failing.

Thanks for any help!
(this is on python 3.10)

Comment: Does installing via a local path work? Such as, `pip install -e MyRepoName1/`?

Answer (score 0):

the problem here was that

`--find-links file:///usr/local/lib/myrepos/MyRepoName1/`

means that it's looking for the files directly in
/usr/local/lib/myrepos/MyRepoName1/

while I have subfolders there.

the only way to achieve that was to edit individual lines within my requirements.txt with @ file:///usr/local/lib/myrepos/MyRepoName1/